# Load a dynamically created document in the browser from a Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, dom, firefox-addon

Is there a way to load a DOM document dynamically created from the scope of a Firefox extension to a tab in the current browser?

I would like to create an HTML report from a Firefox extension and load it in a new tab in the browser.

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument ('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);  
var body = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'body');  
doc.documentElement.appendChild(body);

var div = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("New HTML doc");
body.appendChild(div)

//How to load this document in a new tab?
```

So far, I have only achieved to append the dynamically generated content in the body of an empty template located in the extension directory (chrome://myextension/content/template.html).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean to view/save dynamic source?

Comment: No, I mean to load a document created from scratch via DOM methods from a Firefox extension into the browser.

Comment: ah -- I missed the "firefox extension" part. You mean you've got an extension implemented with XUL + Javascript?

Comment: Yes, I create the document from the Firefox addon and I would like to load it in the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the file manipulation, you will need is the following:

- [temporary file creation](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Creating_temporary_files)
- [Write in a file](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Writing_to_a_file)

Load a file in a new firefox tab:

- [Add Firefos Tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL%3aMethod%3aaddTab)

Some useful link to continue:

- [Mozilla site for development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets)
- [Add-ons for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/): Just download and read the source code of extension is maybe the best self-teaching way to learn.

I hope this will help you,
Good continuation!

Answer (score 1):

It may not be exactly what you want but one solution would be to simply create a file in the temporary directory of the system and to open it in a new tab of your firefox

Comment: That would be ok, can you give some clues on how to do it or point me to an online example / documentation?

Comment: I put a new post for that purpose, I hope you like it!